# Cannot define empty environment variable with Pipenv .env file in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, pipenv

I am new to Pipenv. I want to be able to assign an empty value to environment variables with `.env` file.

Here is my `.env`.

```
FOO=abc
BAR=
```

I activated the virtual environment with `pipenv shell` and expected variable `BAR` to be an empty string, but it was not defined at all.

```
> python -c "import os; print(repr(os.environ.get('FOO', 'Not defined')))"
'abc'
> python -c "import os; print(repr(os.environ.get('BAR', 'Not defined')))"
'Not defined'
```

- OS: Windows 10
- Python 3.9.2
- Pipenv 2020.11.15

However, when I did the same in WSL2 Ubuntu with the same Pipenv version, `BAR` was defined with an empty string as expected.

```
$ python -c "import os; print(repr(os.environ.get('BAR', 'Not defined')))"
''
```

Could anyone give any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe it’s not possible to define empty variable in windows command shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET BAR=
```

in Windows batch is used to unset the variable instead of setting it to an empty value.

So `.env` implementation in pipenv is basically setting any value to any variable defined in the file. There is probably no simple way to define a variable with an empty value in Windows Batch.

Try to modify your script to use some kind of boolean value (0/1, on/off, true/false, …) if you need a boolean, or use a sensible value when either not defined or empty.

```py
from os import getenv

var_x = getenv('BAR', '') or 'default_value'

var_bool = getenv('BAZ', '0').strip() == '1'
```